# In redux+react web app, how to know one async action is finally dispatched to state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Rudx-thunk did a great job to dispatch async actions, it will eventually modify the state fetched in async action. But how do I know the moment when it finally modify the redux state fetched?

In my case, I want to read config from the server, because there are components need these config so I have to render the whole app after the config is fetched. But so far I cannot work out by using redux-thunk or any other redux async middlewares.

**Update #1 show some code to express myself better.**

```
// reducer
(state, action) => Object.assign({}, state, {config: action.config});

// action creator
const fetchConfig = () => (dispatch) => {
    fetch('http://server.com/...')
    .then(config=>dispatch({type: 'LOAD_CONFIG', config}))
}

// connect reducer to state
createStore({config: configReducer})

// render
import { render } from 'react-dom';
render (<App><News /></App>)

// some component consume state.config
@connect(state=>{config: state.config})
const News = props=>(
    <div>
        {(props.config === '...')? <div>...</div> : <div>...</div>}
    </div>
)
```

The above looks good, however due to the action may take time and update the states after the component first render, so the component may display unexpected results. What I really want to do is (I just write down the render part, others should be the same):

```
// render
loadConfigFinished
.then(()=> render((<App><News /></App>)))
```

Or

```
// render
on('loadConfigFinished', ()=> render((<App><News /></App>)));
```

Probably, I should do the 2nd way, just afraid it is not redux-y.

Anyway, the above is just a example showing sometimes we do need to be notified when some action finally dispatch to the redux state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, I gather your question is simply: When do I render a component that depends on data from the server, while waiting for that data, without passing `undefined` into my component?

I would have a container component that connects to the config state, and conditionally renders the component that needs it, or a loading template:

```js
const Container = props => {
  if (props.config) {
    return <ConfiguredComponent config={props.config} />
  } else {
    return <Loading />
  }
}
```

Comment: Smart. But I just worried I have to put the logic into every component using config.

Comment: Yeah that's kind of the general dance with using React/Redux: how do I pass as little state down as possible, since everything gets passed down? ... If config is so ubiquitous, you might want to inline those values on the server, or do server-side rendering.

Comment: I kind think redux-thunk is a walk-around solution to async actions, as it is basically a eventually consistency model. I don't know when it will happen, but sometimes this moment is important esp. when comes to initialising order.

Comment: Check out redux-saga. Even more fine-grained control-flow, using spawned es6 generators, which are super-cool to work with anyway. I think you'll want container components that can decide between rendering or `<Loading />` anyway, though. jsx-control-statements makes writing conditionals in JSX a lot more uniform, if you go that way.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
export function readConfig() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(readingConfig());

    someAsyncFunction((error, result) => {
      if (!error) {
        dispatch(readConfigSuccess(result));
      } else {
        dispatch(readConfigFail(error));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And of course, `readConfigSuccess`, `readConfigFail`, and `readingConfig` are action creator functions that return action objects, e.g.:

```
export const READING_CONFIG = 'READING_CONFIG';
export function readingConfig() {
  return {
    type: READING_CONFIG,
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't solve my problem. I want to use this config in my components, therefore I have to do something like:　readConfig().then( ReactDOM.reander(<div>... </div>).

Comment: I'd have to see some of your code. Could you edit your post to include some of it? Using `ReactDOM.render` that way doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

When your reducers process the readConfigSuccess action, they update the redux state.

The application gets re-rendered with updated props for all state changes so there's nothing special about this particular action.

Except that usually only a small part of the state changes and the rerender looks a lot like the previous render and here I'd expect that a relatively large part of the state gets changed by the reducers for this particular action and a rerender will render a much changed application.

That's not for you to worry about though, it should Just Work.

Or do you mean something else, would you like to do more async work as a result of retrieving the config?

Comment: I didn't express myself clearly, so I updated my question to express myself better, would you take a look?